# Qml slider style, assigning different groove color before and after the slider's handle

Tags: qt, slider, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

So I wanted to create a slider style, similar to the default one, and also more matching to my applications style, but I found it hard to assign a different color before and after the slider's handle.

Here's a simplified version of my code, without gradients, anchor points and other properties:

```
Slider{
            id: widthSlider
            style: SliderStyle {
                    groove: Rectangle {
                        height: widthSlider.height*0.17
                        width: widthSlider.width
                        color: "black"
                        radius: 8
                    }
                    handle: Rectangle {
                        color: "grey"
                    }
                }
        }
```

I tried a rough workaround, to put two rectangles in the slider, anchored to the handle position like this:

```
Slider{
            id: widthSlider
            Rectangle {
                anchors.left: widthSlider.left
                anchors.right: widthSlider.__handlePos
                color: "black"
            }
            Rectangle {
                anchors.left: widthSlider.__handlePos
                anchors.right: widthSlider.right
                color: "white"
            }
     ...
}
```

but I cannot anchor to the handle's position since it's just a double(I get the error: Unable to assign double to QQuickAnchorLine).

Does anyone have an idea of how I could do this in Qml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
Slider {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    value: 0.5
    width: 400
    style: SliderStyle {
        groove: Item {
            implicitHeight: 10
            LinearGradient {
                anchors.fill: parent
                start: Qt.point(0, control.height / 2)
                end: Qt.point(control.width, control.height / 2)
                gradient: Gradient {
                    GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "orange" }
                    GradientStop { position: control.value; color: "brown" }
                    GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "orange" }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or:

```js
Slider {
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    value: 0.5
    width: 400
    style: SliderStyle {
        groove: Rectangle {
            implicitHeight: 10
            color: "lightgrey"
            border {
                color: "#999"
                width: 1
            }
            Rectangle {
                implicitHeight: 10
                color: "orange"
                implicitWidth: control.value * parent.width
                border {
                    color: "#999"
                    width: 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really.

[Here's a picture](http://i.imgur.com/HXuEoUS.png) showing my issue. The first slider is what your code does(changed the third color: "orange" to color: "brown" to make it visible) and the second picture is what I like to do.

I want the groove to change color based on the position of the slider's handle.

On your code, changing the position of the handle does not change the color at all.

Comment: Made a workaround similar to your second example. It kinda works, but surely there must be a better way.

Comment: how can i position the handle to the center of the slidebar

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question. However for future reference the `Rectangle` that represents the colour before the handle should have a width of `styleData.handlePosition`. The below code is from [folibis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39393888/5632060) second solution with this change.

```
Slider {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        value: 0.5
        width: 400
        style: SliderStyle {
            groove: Rectangle {
                implicitHeight: 10
                color: "lightgrey"
                border {
                    color: "#999"
                    width: 1
                }
                Rectangle {
                    implicitHeight: 10
                    color: "orange"
                    implicitWidth: styleData.handlePosition
                    border {
                        color: "#999"
                        width: 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```